# why is flex-basis property getting overridden?

Tags: css, flexbox

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y8d2q3ww/2/

```
.flex-container{display:flex;width:100%}
.square{flex-basis:55px;background:yellow}

<div class='flex-container'>
    <div class="square">M</div>
    <div class="text">some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text </div>    
</div>
```

Only when the text doesn't wrap, the .square's width will be 55px as the flex-basis property sets; but if the text is more than one line, the actual width will be scaled down. So what is behind this? And how do I make the .square area have a fixed width(be it px or %) no matter what content the other flex items hold?

Comment: I'm confused...what are you expecting the final result to look like?

Comment: I just want the .square to be 20% of the parent width, setting it to '55px' was just for demonstration.

Comment: So you can't set "20%"? - http://jsfiddle.net/y8d2q3ww/5/ I'm still confused.

Comment: it is not 20% in your fiddle, it's 69/432 = 15.9%

Comment: The value you quote changes...but your Jquery does not return the updated value. If you re-size the window you can see it changing in size, - http://jsfiddle.net/y8d2q3ww/6/

Comment: even in your fiddle, the  first yellow area's width  is not 20% of its parent, and the second area's width is 116px instead of 200px

Comment: How about now@- http://jsfiddle.net/y8d2q3ww/7/

Comment: I don't see any essential change. The actual widths still are different from what you set.

Comment: Then I dunno what to tell you.

Comment: My question is simple, how do you make the yellow area's actual width exactly 200px, or 20% of its parent's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.square shrinks if .text overflows, because you did not specify [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink), which defaults to 1.

Set it to 0 to get the desired result:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%
}
.square {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-container'>
  <div class="square">M</div>
  <div class="text">some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text</div>
</div>
```